# Continuous measurement of pulse width or frequency in LTSPICE - .meas statement

Tags: ltspice

I want to measure the pulse width of a series of non-deterministic square pulses (See Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH1am.png)). In the end, I would have a vector of the duration of the n-occurrences vs. time of occurrence.

Using `.MEAS` available in Spice simulators, I can only give an occurrence using RISE, FALL or CROSS options.

Any solution or hint?

[image]

Comment: Does "time of occurrence" mean the rising edge, falling edge, or the midpoint of when the pulse hangs high (or low)?

Comment: @SteKulov Time of occurrence would be the time of the trigger to start the measurement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `RISE=` form to make a measurement of the pulsewidth for a specific pulse. So, for example, use `RISE=2` to make a measurement of the second pulse. Something like

```
.MEAS TRAN widthpulse2 TRIG V(node1) VAL=2.5 RISE=2 TARG V(node1) VAL=2.5 FALL=2
```

You will need a separate `.MEAS` for each pulse, and then you will have to do some post-processing of the log file to convert the data to your desired form.